# variable in loop FOR (BATCH)

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop

here is my script

```
set e=0
  for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('type C:\Users\braimm\Desktop\test1.xml') do (

if "%%i" == "======1.3.0.5======" (

set e=1 )
if "%%i" == "====RELEASES====" if "%e%"=="1" (
echo !e!
echo test>>fichierTest.xml )
echo %%i>>fichierTest.xml )
```

my variable still always on 0 , i want a simple thing : if e changed to 1 in an iteration , then e must keep this value for the next iteration .
i'm not sure but i think when start another iteration it becomes 0 .

thanks

Comment: Why do you use both percents and exclamations in `if "%e%"=="1" (
echo !e!`? If you know why you use exclamation marks, then you know the answer to your question!

Comment: Hint: Open a command prompt window, execute there `set /?` and read the __entire__ help output now for this command explaining nearly everything you need to know about usage of environment variables including delayed expansion. Running a command or console application on Windows with parameter `/?` results usually in getting help for this command or application. Or you add [Command-line reference A-Z](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491071.aspx) to bookmarks/favorites of your browser and use it in future.

Comment: thank's i did understand the problem why it doesn't take effect,i just miss to add SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION in my batch file